# How to create an asynchronous RESTful interface with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using Meteor.router to set up a RESTful interface to my web-app. In certain cases I would like to execute the call asynchronously and just tell the caller it is alright.

I have done that like so:

first a Meteor method is defined

```
Meteor.methods( {
   async: function() {
      //do nothing
   }
});
```

this method does nothing because it is only needed to enable the callback

```
Meteor.Router.add( '/fieldData', 'POST', function ( id ) {
   var that = this;
   Meteor.call("async", function(err, res) {
      storeFieldData( that.request.body );
   });

   return [200, 'form data created'];
} );
```

what is done here is, that the Meteor.call is used for its ability to create an async callback.

I am sure there is a more elegant method that my ignorance prevented me from finding. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: `var that = this` prize winning semantics

Comment: that's not very helpful

Comment: like `this` isn't very helpful :P? (that=this) I couldn't resist, but to be helpful I added an answer too

Comment: the statement that = this is required in order to be able to refer to that.request.body inside the anonymous function.

Comment: `var self = this` is better. That != this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is on your server js, which you would have to to give a REST interface you don't have to be bound by asynchronous javascript. For instance you could do :

```
Meteor.Router.add( '/fieldData', 'POST', function ( id ) {
    var result = Meteor.call('foo', this.request.body)
    return result;
});
```

Comment: what you are saying is that there is no use to make the call async?

Comment: Yes you don't really have to, the code is so much easier using a sync style call (keep in mind though only server side code can run this way)

Comment: but node.js will wait until the request is finished before handling the next one. Or is it a misconception on my part?

Comment: yes node uses a single thread, but why it depends on whether the operation you're doing is blocking like a http request, for which you can use `this.unblock` in your method to allow other stuff to run. Fibers actually creates the illusion that the code is synchronous, behind the scenes its still asynchronous code

Comment: the Meteor.methods has an unblock function. this should be work better.

Comment: You can use Fiber(function() { ... }).run() .. to do the same elsewhere like the above

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way and it helps if you want to access other Meteor functionality: use a Fiber

The code looks like this:

```
Meteor.Router.add( '/fieldData', 'POST', function () {
   var body = this.request.body;
   Fiber( function() {
      storeFieldData( body );
   }).run();

   return [200, 'form data created'];
} );
```

What I don't know is how to actually return something from inside the Fiber :-(